# Database table add an extra field or create a new table and left-join

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I'm trying to decide if I should add an extra field to an existing table, that currently has about 4 million rows and growing, or create an auxiliary table and do a left-join? And the new field will be NULL 99% of the time.

Specifically I have a table, say called "entry",  with a field "url",  but now  I need to store an action for that url.  (open in: same window, new window/tab, lightbox/iframe,  etc.)

So,  I could have a new "action_type" table, that has those different actions, and an action_type_id added to the "entry" table that will mostly by null.

Or I could have an entry_has_action_type table having both entry_id, and action_type_id,  and then in my query for "entry" use a left-join to include the action_type if it is present for that row.

I'm thinking I should do the latter or will I pay for adding the left-join (and join on action).

Appreciate any advice!
Thanks,
Ken

Comment: You always have to add a field in the original table, so it is only good when your new table will have multiple columns or at least the column that stores the data is significant bigger than the reference field i.e char(10).

Comment: I think you could test this for yourself quicker than asking us.

Comment: @Strawberry ha, true enough!  and I've just done that and there's no significant performance hit to the double left-join, tested using a backup `entry` table with 6 million rows, so that's what i'm going with.   

Original `entry` table that is untouched,  and new tables: `action`, and `entry_has_action`.    

and then a query like
`select action.label from entry left join entry_has_action using(entry_id) left join action using(action_id) where ... `